# convert pdf output into motion gif

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following codes gives an animation of cos x, which is modified from the one by Henri Menke. Could you please help to convert this pdf output into GIF using imagemagick. I could not install the imagemagick.

[image]

```
 \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \providecommand{\myts}{\biolinum\scshape{M\hspace{-.061em}\raisebox{-.26351ex}{Y}\hspace{-.0961em}T\hspace{-.05161em}\raisebox{.2451ex}{S}}}
    \usepackage{libertineotf}
    \definecolor{darkcerulean}{rgb}{0.03, 0.27, 0.49}
    \usepackage{lucimatx}%remove this if the font is not available.
    \definecolor{bleudefrance}{rgb}{0.19, 0.55, 0.91}
    \begin{document}
    \foreach \angle in {0,10,...,360}
    {
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        % fill circle and plot
        \fill[yellow!50] (-1,0) arc (0:\angle:1) -- (-2,0) -- cycle;
        \fill[yellow!50] plot[smooth,domain=0:\angle] (pi/180*\x,{cos(\x)}) |- (0,0);
        % draw connection
        \draw (-2,0) +(\angle:1) circle (1.2pt) -- (pi/180*\angle,{cos(\angle)}) circle (1.2pt);
        % draw axes an ticks
        \draw (-3.5,0) -- (7,0);
        \foreach \deg in {90, 180, 270, 360}
          \draw (pi/180*\deg,2pt) -- (pi/180*\deg,-2pt) node[below] {$\deg^\circ$};
        \draw (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2);
        \foreach \y in {-1,-0.5,0.5,1}
          \draw (2pt,\y) -- (-2pt,\y) node[left] {$\y$};
        % draw plot and circle outline
        \draw plot[smooth,domain=0:360] (pi/180*\x,{cos(\x)});
        \draw (-2,0) circle (1);
    \draw[color=bleudefrance] (3.05,.905) node {\bf\scalebox{1.17596}{\myts}};
    \draw[color=darkcerulean] (3.0425921085,.67295) node {\it\scalebox{.2196875}{Mathematical Young Talent  Search}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want `cos(x)` or `sin(x)` animation?

Comment: I want the gif of cos(x), which is produced from the pdf output of the above.

Comment: The animation with `cos(x)` has no meaning...

Comment: Your only problem is the conversion from PDF to GIF with Imagemagick? How is that related to (La)TeX in any way? If so, I'd say this question is off-topic for this site, and should be closed.

Comment: Could you help to move the question to appropriate place?